# extract email addresses from Mailgun using python

Tags: python, python-requests, mailgun

I am trying to extract all my email subscribers from Mailgun using this:

```
members = requests.get('https://api.mailgun.net/v3/lists/<address>/members',
                           auth=auth
                           )
```

This works however it limits the number of subscribers to 100. I have 600 people on my list and need to access them all to perform some logic. I understand there is a way to over-ride the 100 record limit but have not found anything. Any thoughts? I'm stuck.

Mailgun documentation: [Click Here!](https://documentation.mailgun.com/en/latest/api-mailinglists.html#mailing-lists)

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation, it looks like its API will take a `limit` parameter.  You should be able to get all your subscribers via something like:

```
members = requests.get('https://api.mailgun.net/v3/lists/<address>/members',
                           auth=auth,
                           params={'limit':100, 'skip': 100}
                           )
```

Comment: I've tried that. Anything over 100 result in 404 status code

Comment: @freefly0313:  Does adding the `skip` parameter help?

Comment: Unfortunately no. I'm totally stumped